# How to launch java application without having to specify classpath?

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, launcher

I'm new to java and I'm experimenting with hello world app. 
I've exported the app from Eclipse into a jar, i DID specify the launch configuration, and when I ran it from command line, I retrieved

```
Error: Could not find or load main class
```

That can be fixed by specifying class path like this:

```
java -cp .:myjar.jar MyMainClass
```

However, this is really inconvenient. Is there any way, preferably through eclipse, to specify MyMainClass as a metadata inside the jar file so I don't have to write it down every time I launch the app?

Comment: Did you set the manifest for the .jar?

Comment: how do you specify manifest file in Eclipse?

Comment: [This will help for manifest file](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=502171)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can by writing a manifest file, and then running java -jar Yourjarfile.jar